# Data from mongoDb Not showing on Handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am trying to show some data from mongoDb but it is not showing on Handlebars. but while i log this then it showing properly..

Get Method Code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
db.collection('Product').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    res.render('shop/index', {  title: 'Shoping Cart', products: 
result});
    console.log(result);
  })
})
```

Handlebars Code:

```
{{# each products }}
<div class="row">
    {{# each this}}
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{ this.imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive" style="max-heigenter code hereht: 150px">
       <div class="caption">
       <h3>{{ this.title }}</h3>
       <p><{{ this.description }}</p>
       <div class="clearfix">
       <div class="price pull-left">${{ this.price }}</div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Button</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   {{/each}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

After Log The Arry is showing Properly:

```
[ { _id: 5a16f0e0480b08283a5d0373,
    imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    title: 'Gothic Video Game',
    description: 'Awsome Game!!!',
    price: '10' },
  { _id: 5a16f8dfd4c0bf2c1e490e46,
    imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d2/Need_for_Speed_Undercover_cover.jpg/256px-Need_for_Speed_Undercover_cover.jpg',
    title: 'Need For Speed',
    description: 'This is Awsome racing Game!!!',
    price: '20' },
  { _id: 5a16f90dd4c0bf2c1e490e47,
    imagePath: 'https://media.newyorker.com/photos/590977c9019dfc3494ea2f7f/master/w_649,c_limit/Johnston-Clash-Clans.jpg',
    title: 'Clash Of Clans',
    description: 'Most Popular Online Game Ever!!!',
    price: '55' },
  { _id: 5a17a7baf326291813be29fe,
    imagePath: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    price: '' } ]
```

Comment: I think it might be a special type of object, don’t really remember. Is there a .toObject() function you can call? I’m thinking if that could cause problems.

Comment: In my find() function I am converting the object as arry and sent to to show on Handlebars.